# Python HTTP POST JSON error with sending base64 in variable

Tags: python, json

Im trying to POST base64 image to an existing service, but when i add variable (**img**) to to reqeust body, i am getting error: **JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)**

```
import requests
img = base64.encodebytes(open
                         ('/x/b51ad9ac-b648-40ce-ac7b-ce0c7a6af65b.jpeg', 
                          'rb').read())#.decode('utf-8')
newHeaders = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}

response = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1/api/cv/pdm/outer/v2/', 
                         data={'caseId': '123123123', 
                               'partNo': 'bumper', 
                               'imageName': 'hz.jpeg',
                               'imageData': img,
                               'timestamp': '1596610139236'}, headers=newHeaders)
 
print("Status code: ", response.status_code)
response_Json = response.json()
print(response_Json)

print("Content-Type is ", response_Json)
```

Whats wrong? Thanks in advance

**Full log of exception during JSONDecode**

```
*Status code:  413
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-82-7cc8a2bb1cf2> in <module>
     20 print("Status code: ", response.status_code)
     21 
---> 22 response_Json = response.json()
     23 
     24 print(response_Json)
~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/models.py in json(self, **kwargs)
    895                     # used.
    896                     pass
--> 897         return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
    898 
    899     @property
~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    346             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    347             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 348         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    349     if cls is None:
    350         cls = JSONDecoder
~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
    335 
    336         """
--> 337         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    338         end = _w(s, end).end()
    339         if end != len(s):
~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    353             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    354         except StopIteration as err:
--> 355             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    356         return obj, end
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)*
```

Comment: Try to print the raw response body to see what it contains…!?

Comment: There is error during JSONDecode, i added more info to my question

Comment: first check `response.text` to see what you get. Maybe you get plain text or HTML with warning or useful message.

Comment: if you want to send `json` then you can use `json=...` instead `data=...` and it should convert it to `JSON` and add header `Content-type` automatically. If you use `data=` then you need `data=json.dumps(...)`

Comment: Thank you guys, i was confused that my request had an error, but it were in response.

Comment: when I run your code then `response.text` shows HTML with `404 Not Found` - it seems you use wrong URL and it makes all your problem.

Comment: @furas nah, url just hidden from public :)

Comment: you still should check what you get in `response.text` because in response you don't have json data. And you should also run server in console/terminal to see all messages created by server. Maybe it display error message when it get wrong data and it sends empty response.